# Cancel waiting tasks in a ThreadPoolExector

Tags: java, android, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'd like to cancel all the tasks waiting in a ThreadPoolExecutor.

For example if the tasks **A** and **B** are running and **C,D,E** waiting (because the thread pool size is 2) I want to cancel C,D,E leaving A and B end normally.

How can I do this in a easy way other than maintaining the list of the Runnables and calling threadpool.remove(runnable) for each one of them?

Thanks

Comment: When you do that, is the executor supposed to shutdown (hint hint) and not to be used again?

Comment: No, new tasks can be queued after that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All tasks that not running placed in special queue. You can get this queue via getQueue().

Your code should looks like this:

```
threadPoolExector.getQueue().clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could call .cancel() on your tasks that you want to remove - ie. iterate some list with tasks and check using `instanceof` if they are of C,D,E type. As a list you could use `threadPoolExector.getQueue()` as KamiSempai suggested.

I am actually using `ScheduledExecutorService` and I have method:

`cancelTasksOfType(Class<? extends TaskBase) taskClassToCancel)`

inside it I'am cancelling each task that passes test with `instanceof` on taskClassToCancel